# StackOverflowError because of big "conf/routes" file in Play Version 2.0.1

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

In my project I would like to have clean URLs. Thus I creates entries in conf/routes like:

```
GET   /switzerland  controllers.Application.country(countryCode = "CH")
GET   /germany      controllers.Application.country(countryCode = "DE")
...
GET   /:countryCode  controllers.Application.country(countryCode: String)
```

My list is over 130 entries long and creates a StackOverflowError. Any help on how to prevent the error is highly appreciated. Maybe there is also a much more elegant solution to this problem.

Java-Version:

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3646)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

I created a small sample project, to reproduce it (at least on my Mac):
https://github.com/sunsations/play_2.0.1_routes_stackoverflowerror

Comment: What does MacBook Air have to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, problem occurs so I think that better place for that would be [Play's Lighthouse](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/overview)

In meanwhile you can solve it fast and easy with ONE route:

```
GET   /:countryName    controllers.Application.country(countryName : String)
```

Then in `country()` action you can just get `countryCode` from DB identified by String `countryName`

edit:

BTW, using this approach it will be easier to use UTF links ie `domain.tld/Росси́я` instead of `domain.tld/Russia`

Comment: You're welcome :) would you kindly create a ticket for this issue at Play's Lighthous ?

Comment: Done: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/463-stackoverflowerror-because-of-big-confroutes-file-in-play-version-201